STM32L432KC used for negative voltage?
My TIA circuit's opamp needs a negative supply in order to get a output with a 2V dc bias and ac signal that the stm adc can sample. This is needed since the opamp needs a ~3V difference between input and supply. I want to use the forward voltage drop over the photodiode to decrease its capacitance, so the circuit will be able to function at a higher speed.
Can I just connect the stm like in the picture to create this negative supply?


What else does it connect to? Is that connection ground referenced?

The other source is a 12 V dc voltage supply, so there is the 12V and gnd from.

Source yes, but any other wired outputs or inputs? Please draw a block diagram.

The ADC is also connected (updated picture)

You’ll need a voltage divider anyway to protect the ADC input from the possible 12 V supply from your opamp. At which point you’d might as well bias your -5 V to 0 and squeeze down +12 to 5 V. Assuming your MCU runs on 5 V. I’ll try to make a proper answer with schematic when I get home.

I just used a 9V battery, since I was unsure.

Even 9 V is enough to burn up a 5 V MCU. Just throw in a -5 V charge pump to generate your negative bias?

A voltage lower as -0.3V and higher as 3.6V should in principle damage the MCU I am using, so -5 or -9V doesn't make the difference. Do you have a suggestion to limit the voltage between those values. I was thinking about a 3.3V zener diode for the positive, but not sure about negative protection.
